# Does referring to each other by number in group meetings lead to better results?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, io-psychology, military-psychology

I've learned that the pilots of the [Red Arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Arrows) never refer to each other by name but by number in the briefing room in order to avoid conflict.
Is there a name for this trick? Do any studies say this kind of psychological trick leads to better results? Are there any applications in other fields?

Answer (score 1):

This is way outside of my area, but reducing identity expression definitely can increase group conformity. This is the basic idea underlying e.g. school uniforms and cultural restrictions in totalitarian regimes. It might be important to keep in mind that identity expression could promote many positive outcomes (greater creativity, more flexible approaches to problem solving, etc) in addition to increased conflict.